# Hidden tor exit nodes

Tags: onion-services

I was wondering can I run an hidden exit note that only few people know of it, somehow hidden from others?

If not can I protect it via password or something so nobody else can access it?

Or instead should I use a VPN? Is security the same?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add bridge relays](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10631/how-to-add-bridge-relays)

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with some kind of hidden exit node? What usage do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering can I run an hidden exit note that only few people know of it, somehow hidden from others?

No.

> If not can I protect it via password or something so nobody else can access it?

No.

> Or instead should I use a VPN?

Maybe.

> Is security the same?

No.